# Multi-input Multi-output Model with Keras Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, functional-api

As described in figure 1, I have 3 models which each apply to a particular domain.

The 3 models are trained separately with different datasets.
[image]

And inference is sequential :

[image]

I tried to parallelize the call of these 3 models thanks to the Multiprocess library of python but it is very unstable and it is not advised.

Here's the idea I got to make sure to do this all at once:

As the 3 models share a common pretrained-model, I want to make a single model that has multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

As the following drawing shows:
[image]

Like that during the inference, I will call a single model which will do all 3 operations at the same time.

[image]

I saw that with The Functional API of KERAS, it is possible but I have no idea how to do that.
The inputs of the datasets have the same dimension. These are pictures of (200,200,3).

If anyone has an example of a Multi-Input Multi-output model that shares a common structure, I'm all ok.

### UPADE

Here is the example of my code but it returns an error because of the `layers. concatenate (...)` line which propagates a shape that is not taken into account by the `EfficientNet` model.

```
age_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), name="age_inputs")
    
gender_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
                               , name="gender_inputs")
    
emotion_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), 
                                name="emotion_inputs")


inputs = layers.concatenate([age_inputs, gender_inputs, emotion_inputs])
inputs = layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation="relu")(inputs)    
model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, 
                   input_tensor=inputs, weights="imagenet")
    

model.trainable = False

inputs = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(model.output)
inputs = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)

top_dropout_rate = 0.2
inputs = layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name="top_dropout")(inputs)

age_outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", 
                          name="age_pred")(inputs)
gender_outputs = layers.Dense(GENDER_NUM_CLASSES, 
                              activation="softmax", 
                              name="gender_pred")(inputs)
emotion_outputs = layers.Dense(EMOTION_NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax", 
                             name="emotion_pred")(inputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[age_inputs, gender_inputs, emotion_inputs], 
              outputs =[age_outputs, gender_outputs, emotion_outputs], 
              name="EfficientNet")

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
model.compile(loss={"age_pred" : "mse", 
                   "gender_pred":"categorical_crossentropy", 
                    "emotion_pred":"categorical_crossentropy"}, 
                   optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])

(age_train_images, age_train_labels), (age_test_images, age_test_labels) = reg_data_loader.load_data(...)
(gender_train_images, gender_train_labels), (gender_test_images, gender_test_labels) = cat_data_loader.load_data(...)
(emotion_train_images, emotion_train_labels), (emotion_test_images, emotion_test_labels) = cat_data_loader.load_data(...)

 model.fit({'age_inputs':age_train_images, 'gender_inputs':gender_train_images, 'emotion_inputs':emotion_train_images},
         {'age_pred':age_train_labels, 'gender_pred':gender_train_labels, 'emotion_pred':emotion_train_labels},
                 validation_split=0.2, 
                       epochs=5, 
                            batch_size=16)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can do that easily in `tf. keras` using its awesome Functional API. Here we will walk you through how to build multi-out with a different type (`classification` and `regression`) using Functional API.

According to your last diagram, you need one input model and three outputs of **different types**. To demonstrate, we will use `MNIST` which is a handwritten dataset. It's normally a **10** class classification problem data set. From it, we will create an additionally **2** class classifier (whether a digit is `even` or `odd`) and also a **1** regression part (which is to predict the square of a digit, i.e for image input of 9, it should give approximately it's square).

---

**Data Set**

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(xtrain, ytrain), (_, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# 10 class classifier 
y_out_a = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, num_classes=10) 

# 2 class classifier, even or odd 
y_out_b = keras.utils.to_categorical((ytrain % 2 == 0).astype(int), num_classes=2) 

# regression, predict square of an input digit image
y_out_c = tf.square(tf.cast(ytrain, tf.float32))
```

So, our training pairs will be `xtrain` and `[y_out_a, y_out_b, y_out_c]`, the same as your last diagram.

---

**Model Building**

Let's build the model accordingly using the Functional API of `tf. keras`. See the model definition below. The `MNIST` samples are a `28 x 28` grayscale image. So our input is set in that way. I'm guessing your data set is probably RGB, so change the input dimension accordingly.

```
input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="original_img")
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

out_a = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='10cls')(x)
out_b = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='2cls')(x)
out_c = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='1rg')(x)

encoder = keras.Model( inputs = input, outputs = [out_a, out_b, out_c], name="encoder")
```

```
# Let's plot 
keras.utils.plot_model(
    encoder
)
```

[image]

One thing to note, while defining `out_a`, `out_b`, and  `out_c` during model definition we set their `name` variable which is very important. Their names are set `'10cls'`, `'2cls'`, and `'1rg'` respectively. You can also see this from the above diagram (last 3 tails).

---

**Compile and Run**

Now, we can see why that `name` variable is important. In order to run the model, we need to compile it first with the proper `loss` function, `metrics`, and `optimizer`. Now, if you know that, for the `classification` and `regression` problem, the `optimizer` can be the same but for the `loss` function and `metrics` should be changed. And in our model, which has a multi-type output model (2 classifications and 1 regression), we need to set proper `loss` and `metrics` for each of these types. Please, see below how it's done.

```
encoder.compile(
    loss = {
        "10cls": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        "2cls": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        "1rg": tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    },

    metrics = {
        "10cls": 'accuracy',
        "2cls": 'accuracy',
        "1rg": 'mse'
    },

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
)
```

See, each last output of our above model, which is here represented by their `name` variables. And we set proper compilation to them. Hope you understand this part. Now, time to train the model.

```
encoder.fit(xtrain, [y_out_a, y_out_b, y_out_c], epochs=30, verbose=2)

Epoch 1/30
1875/1875 - 6s - loss: 117.7318 - 10cls_loss: 3.2642 - 4cls_loss: 0.9040 - 1rg_loss: 113.5637 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.6057 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.8671 - 1rg_mse: 113.5637
Epoch 2/30
1875/1875 - 5s - loss: 62.1696 - 10cls_loss: 0.5151 - 4cls_loss: 0.2437 - 1rg_loss: 61.4109 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.8845 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.9480 - 1rg_mse: 61.4109
Epoch 3/30
1875/1875 - 5s - loss: 50.3159 - 10cls_loss: 0.2804 - 4cls_loss: 0.1371 - 1rg_loss: 49.8985 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.9295 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.9641 - 1rg_mse: 49.8985


Epoch 28/30
1875/1875 - 5s - loss: 15.5841 - 10cls_loss: 0.1066 - 4cls_loss: 0.0891 - 1rg_loss: 15.3884 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.9726 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.9715 - 1rg_mse: 15.3884
Epoch 29/30
1875/1875 - 5s - loss: 15.2199 - 10cls_loss: 0.1058 - 4cls_loss: 0.0859 - 1rg_loss: 15.0281 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.9736 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.9727 - 1rg_mse: 15.0281
Epoch 30/30
1875/1875 - 5s - loss: 15.2178 - 10cls_loss: 0.1136 - 4cls_loss: 0.0854 - 1rg_loss: 15.0188 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.9722 - 4cls_accuracy: 0.9736 - 1rg_mse: 15.0188
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7ff42c18e110>
```

That's how each of the outputs of the last layer optimizes by their concern `loss` function. FYI, one thing to mention, there is an essential parameter while `.compile` the model which you might need: [`loss_weights`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) - to weight the loss contributions of **different model outputs**. See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499018/9215780) on this.

---

**Prediction / Inference**

Let's see some output. We now hope this model will predict **3** things: (1) is what the digit is, (2) is it even or odd, and (3) its square value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(xtrain[0])
```

[image]

If we like to quickly check the output layers of our model

```
encoder.output

[<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 10) dtype=float32 (created by layer '10cls')>,
 <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 2) dtype=float32 (created by layer '4cls')>,
 <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32 (created by layer '1rg')>]
```

Passing this `xtrain[0]` (which we know **5**) to the model to do predictions.

```
# we expand for a batch dimension: (1, 28, 28, 1)
pred10, pred2, pred1 = encoder.predict(tf.expand_dims(xtrain[0], 0))

# regression: square of the input dgit image 
pred1 
array([[22.098022]], dtype=float32)

# even or odd, surely odd 
pred2.argmax()
0

# which number, surely 5
pred10.argmax()
5
```

---

## Update

Based on your comment, we can extend the above model to take multi-input too. We need to change things. To demonstrate, we will use `train` and `test` samples of the `mnist` data set to the model as a multi-input.

```
(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

xtrain = xtrain[:10000] # both input sample should be same number 
ytrain = ytrain[:10000] # both input sample should be same number

y_out_a = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, num_classes=10)
y_out_b = keras.utils.to_categorical((ytrain % 2 == 0).astype(int), num_classes=2)
y_out_c = tf.square(tf.cast(ytrain, tf.float32))

print(xtrain.shape, xtest.shape) 
print(y_out_a.shape, y_out_b.shape, y_out_c.shape)
# (10000, 28, 28) (10000, 28, 28)
# (10000, 10) (10000, 2) (10000,)
```

Next, we need to modify some parts of the above model to take **multi-input**. And next if you now plot, you will see the new graph.

```
input0 = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img2")
input1 = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img1")
concate_input = layers.Concatenate()([input0, input1])

x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(concate_input)
...
...
...
# multi-input , multi-output
encoder = keras.Model( inputs = [input0, input1], 
                       outputs = [out_a, out_b, out_c], name="encoder")
```

[image]

Now, we can train the model as follows

```
# multi-input, multi-output
encoder.fit([xtrain, xtest], [y_out_a, y_out_b, y_out_c], 
             epochs=30, batch_size = 256, verbose=2)

Epoch 1/30
40/40 - 1s - loss: 66.9731 - 10cls_loss: 0.9619 - 2cls_loss: 0.4412 - 1rg_loss: 65.5699 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.7627 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.8815 - 1rg_mse: 65.5699
Epoch 2/30
40/40 - 0s - loss: 60.5408 - 10cls_loss: 0.8959 - 2cls_loss: 0.3850 - 1rg_loss: 59.2598 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.7794 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.8928 - 1rg_mse: 59.2598
Epoch 3/30
40/40 - 0s - loss: 57.3067 - 10cls_loss: 0.8586 - 2cls_loss: 0.3669 - 1rg_loss: 56.0813 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.7856 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.8951 - 1rg_mse: 56.0813
...
...
Epoch 28/30
40/40 - 0s - loss: 29.1198 - 10cls_loss: 0.4775 - 2cls_loss: 0.2573 - 1rg_loss: 28.3849 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.8616 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.9131 - 1rg_mse: 28.3849
Epoch 29/30
40/40 - 0s - loss: 27.5318 - 10cls_loss: 0.4696 - 2cls_loss: 0.2518 - 1rg_loss: 26.8104 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.8645 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.9142 - 1rg_mse: 26.8104
Epoch 30/30
40/40 - 0s - loss: 27.1581 - 10cls_loss: 0.4620 - 2cls_loss: 0.2446 - 1rg_loss: 26.4515 - 10cls_accuracy: 0.8664 - 2cls_accuracy: 0.9158 - 1rg_mse: 26.4515
```

Now, we can test the multi-input model and get multi-out from it.

```
pred10, pred2, pred1 = encoder.predict(
    [
         tf.expand_dims(xtrain[0], 0),
         tf.expand_dims(xtrain[0], 0)
    ]
)

# regression part 
pred1
array([[25.13295]], dtype=float32)

# even or odd 
pred2.argmax()
0

# what digit 
pred10.argmax()
5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
In my situation, the data (x, y) comes from different datasets.
I should rather have something like this in the model.fit (..) part, I think:

model.fit ({'input1': x_input1, 'input2': x_input2, 'input3': x_input3},
                         {'output1': y_output1, 'output2': y_output2, 'output3': y_output3},
                             validation_split = 0.2,
                                 epochs = 5,
                                     batch_size = 16)


My big problem is how to mix the 3 inputs and introduce them in the same model.

Comment: I updated my post adding my code to give you an idea of what I want to do.

Comment: I use a pre-trained model (EfficienceNet) just after Concatenate()... and I get this error: ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv2d_196/kernel:0 due to variable shape (3, 3, 6, 32) and value shape (32, 3, 3, 3) are incompatible

Comment: In your case after `concate` two inputs, it shape gets `height` x `width` x 6. And then you pass this to the image net models that take the input shape of `height` x `width` x 3. To tackle this, just add this layer `Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same')` right after the concate and before the image net model.

Comment: It will create feature maps of the same input dimension but with 3 channels which further will acceptable to the image net model.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I have a new error on the pre-trained weight: ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 130 layers into a model with 131 layers.

Comment: Please update your question with the last modified code. Just include the model definition part.

Comment: I updated my code but you can test it on this colab :  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gjxgYjt3jWKZNSCJqRcyoDPDhTUYlGoj#scrollTo=VH446MEfqWb2

Comment: (1), you should use `layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation="relu")` - padding same is important. (2), use this `model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet")(inputs)`.  You can't use `input_tensor` now.

Comment: Thanks. it worked :) but I have a new error. You can see it on the colab. It is on the line layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D...

AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'output'

Comment: My finetuning comes from the following example from keras: https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/

Comment: Try [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cnt_VDh3TRp4GR3ZKn2FLGTVlEbk2U3m?usp=sharing).  The link you shared, used `layer.Input` that passes as `input_tensor` to the image net model. Burt in your case it comes from the `layer.concate`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it worked well.
The last difficulty I had was with the sample size. It had to be the same for all inputs. I fixed that in the preprocessing.

Comment: If it solves your question, please mark it as the right answer. Thanks.