# How to build a Tensorflow model with more than one input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to create a Tensorflow neural network model using the Functional API, but I'm not sure how to separate the input into two. I wanted to do something like: given an input, its first half goes to the first part of the neural network, its second half goes to the second part, and each input is passed through the layers until they concatenate, go through another layer and finally reach the output. I thought of something like the snippet of code below, along with a quick sketch.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def define_model(self):
    input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,)) #input is a 1D vector containing 7 elements, split as 4 and 3
    input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))

    layer1_1 = Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(input1)
    layer2_1 = Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_1)

    layer1_2 = Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(input2)
    layer2_2 = Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_2)

    concat_layer = tf.keras.concatenate([layer2_1,layer2_2], axis = 0)
    layer3 = Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(concat_layer)

    output = Dense(4)(layer3) #no activation

    self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [input1,input2],outputs = output)
    self.model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
    return self.model
```

[image]

First of all, should I add any Dropout or BatchNormalization layers in this model?

Also, the first 4 elements of the input array are binary (like [1,0,0,1] or [0,1,1,1]), while the other 3 can be any real number. Should I treat the 1st "column" of the neural network differently than the 2nd one, given that the first operates with inputs in the 0<x<1 range, while the 2nd one doesn't?

It sounds right, but I can't really test if it should work or not, as I would have to rework A LOT of the code to generate enough data to train it. Am I going in the right direction or should I be doing something different? Would this code work at all?

EDIT: I'm having issues during training. Suppose that I want to train the model like this (the values don't matter all that much, what's important is the data type):

```
#this snippet generates training data - nothing real, just test examples. Also, I changed the output layer from 4 elements to just 1 to test it.
A1=[np.array([[1.,0,0,1]]),np.array([[0,1.,0]])]
B1=np.array([7])

c=np.array([[5,-4,1,-1],[2,3,-1]], dtype = object)
A2 = [[np.random.randint(2, size= [1,4]),np.random.randint(2, size= [1,3])] for i in range(1000)]
B2 = np.array([np.sum(A[i][0]*c[0])+np.sum(A[i][1]*c[1]) for i in range(1000)]) 

model.fit(A1,B1, epochs = 50, verbose=False) #this works!
model.fit(A2,B2, epochs = 50, verbose=False) #but this doesn't.
```

FINAL EDIT: here are the predict() and predict_on_batch() functions.

```
def predict(a,b):
    pred = m.predict([a,b])
    return pred

def predict_b(c,d):
    preds = m.predict_on_batch([c,d])
    return preds

#a, b, c and d must look like this:
a = [np.array([0,1,0,1])]
b = [np.array([0,0,1])]

c =        [np.array([1, 0, 0, 1]), 
            np.array([0, 1, 1, 1]), 
            np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]), 
            np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]), 
            np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])] 

d =        [np.array([1, 0, 1]),
            np.array([0, 0, 1]),
            np.array([0, 1, 1]),
            np.array([1, 1, 1]),
            np.array([0, 0, 0])]
#notice that all of those should follow the same pattern, which is a list of arrays.
```

The rest of the code is under M. Innat's answer.

Comment: Split the input Numpy Array when passing in the model. `X_train_r, X_train_l = np.split(X_train,2)`

Comment: Network design is not the issue. But you must prepare your input data first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-input Multi-output Model with Keras Functional API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845924/multi-input-multi-output-model-with-keras-functional-api)

Comment: @M.Innat not actually, it just concatenates the inputs and that's it... I wanted both inputs to go through a neural network before being concatenated.

Comment: both input -- that means the model should be multi-input?

Comment: Yes. Multi-input, single output. Exactly like in the sketch. I edited the original post for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some issue with your code. I will try to answer the main issue here and discard some side questions such as whether you should use `Dropout` or `BatchNormalization` layers in your model or not because that's totally out of the scope of your main question and also irrelevant.

---

If you try to build your model, using `m = define_model()`, I'm pretty sure you will encounter the following error:

```
layer2_1 = Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_1)
layer2_2 = Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_2)
concat_layer = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([layer2_1, layer2_2], axis = 0)

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes 
except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 4), (None, 3)]
```

The correct `axis` should be by default `-1` or `1` but not `0` while concatenating nonidentical shape (e.g. `Dense(4)`, `Dense(3)`).  You either set the same output shape which is `Dense(3)` to `Dense(4)` or set `axis = 1`. Let's pick one (according to your draw):

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def define_model():
    input1 = Input(shape=(4,)) 
    input2 = Input(shape=(3,))

    layer1_1 = layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(input1)
    layer2_1 = layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_1)

    layer1_2 = layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(input2)
    layer2_2 = layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(layer1_2)

    concat_layer = layers.concatenate([layer2_1, layer2_2], axis = 1) 
    layer3 = layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)(concat_layer)

    output = layers.Dense(4)(layer3) 
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [input1,input2],outputs = output)
    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
    return model

m = define_model()
```

More details, see the output shape for choosing `axis` param:

```
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(np.arange(10, 20).reshape(5, 2))
print(x1.shape, x2.shape)
# (5, 8) (5, 8)

# using axis = 0
concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)([x1, x2])
concatted.shape
# TensorShape([10, 8])

# using axis = 1
concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x1, x2])
concatted.shape
# TensorShape([5, 16])
```

---

**Test Model**

The input that works for you:

```
A1_i = np.array([[1.,0, 0,1]])
A1_j = np.array([[0, 1., 0]])
B1   = np.array([4])

print(type(A1_i), type(A1_j), type(B1))
print(A1_i.shape, A1_j.shape, B1.shape)
m.fit([A1_i, A1_j], B1, epochs = 2, verbose=2)
```

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 4) (1, 3) (1,)
Epoch 1/2
584ms/step - loss: 15.9902
Epoch 2/2
4ms/step - loss: 15.8900
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fb1b484b890>
```

The other parts that didn't work for you have several issues, first model input should be a `numpy` array, not a `list`. The second issue came from the modeling part, which concatenates. However, the correct way should be as follows:

```
c = np.array([[5,-4,1,-1],[2,3,-1]], dtype = object)

A2_i = np.random.randint(10, size = [100,4])
A2_j = np.random.randint(10, size = [100,3])
B2   = np.array( [np.sum(A2_i[i][0]*c[0]) + 
                  np.sum(A2_j[i][1]*c[1]) for i in range(100)]) 

print(type(A2_i), type(A2_j), type(B2))
print(A2_i.shape, A2_j.shape, B2.shape)
m.fit([A2_i, A2_j], B2, epochs = 2, verbose=2)
```

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(100, 4) (100, 3) (100,)
Epoch 1/2
4ms/step - loss: 683.9537
Epoch 2/2
4ms/step - loss: 681.0673
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fb1600a8d50>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I edited the original post to add predict() and predict_on_batch() functions.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Do you want anything to specific regarding your question? I don't understand why do you mention the updated part?

Comment: Oh, that's just to help someone who eventually reads this post and faces the same problems I did, just to make their lives a bit easier :)