# Loss function and Loss Weight for Multi-Output Keras Classification model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I am trying to understand the loss function using Keras functional API.
I have a sample multi-output model based on the B-CNN model.

```py
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input')

#--- block 1 ---
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

#--- coarse 1 branch ---
c_1_bch = Flatten(name='c_flatten')(x)
c_1_bch = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='c_dense')(c_1_bch)
c_1_bch = BatchNormalization()(c_1_bch)
c_1_bch = Dropout(0.5)(c_1_bch)
c_1_pred = Dense(num_c, activation='softmax', name='pred_coarse')(c_1_bch)

#--- block 3 ---
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

#--- fine block ---
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc_1')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
fine_pred = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='pred_fine')(x)


model = keras.Model(inputs= [img_input],
                        outputs= [c_1_pred, fine_pred],
                        name='B-CNN_Model')
```

This classification model takes one input and provides 2 predictions.
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845924/multi-input-multi-output-model-with-keras-functional-api#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20we%20can,how%20it%27s%20done.), we need to compile it first with the proper loss function, metrics, and optimizer by mentioning the `name` variables for each output layer.

I have done this in the following way.

```py
model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.003, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True),
              loss={'pred_coarse':'mse',
                    'pred_fine':'categorical_crossentropy'}, 
              loss_weights={'pred_coarse':beta,
                            'pred_fine':gamma},
              metrics={'pred_coarse':'accuracy',
                       'pred_fine':'accuracy'})
```

**[Note:** Here, output layer `pred_coarse` is using Mean Square Error and `pred_fine` is using Categorical Cross Entropy loss function. The loss_weights `beta` and `gamma` are variable and update the value after certain epochs using `keras.callbacks.Callback` function **]**

Now, My question is, **what happens if we compile the model without mentioning the `name` variables for each output layer and provide only one function instead?** For example, we compile the model as follows:

```py
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.003, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              loss_weights=[beta, gamma],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Unlike the previous compile example, this one uses the Categorical Cross Entropy loss function. The model compiles and runs without any errors. **Does the model using Categorical Cross Entropy loss function for both `pred_coarse` and `pred_fine` output layers?**

Comment: Yes, your model would apply categorical cross entropy for all outputs. Your output should be like your input's labels, so the labels of `img_input` should be two elements per feature.

Comment: Thank you @Djinn for clearing the concept.
Btw, What do you mean by "labels of `img_input` should be two elements per feature"? Does it mean the number of protection classes should be two? In that case, it can be more than two classes.

Comment: If you have features that map to two labels in the output, you'll need similarly structured labels in the input to compare against when calculating loss. If feature `x` corresponds with output `[[1], [2]]`, the only way to calculate loss is to compare with the true label, for example `[[3], [4]]`. It has nothing to do with the number of classes.