# how to `set_shape` of `Tensor` to a muli-input dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a Dataset with multiple input, which can be feed into a model with multiple inputs. It works fine when I'm working with single input, then I can easily set the shape using `set_shape` of that tensor inside my `Dataset.map` function. But now I don't know which shape I should set the tensor to.

Related information:

- `x_img1` is 10 dimensional 1024 by 1024 image
- `x_img2` is a 2D, 32 by 64 image

Here is my code:

```
def read_image(path, rel):
    # blah blah blah, read somehow
    return image

def read_image1(path1, filter0):
    # blah blah blah, read somehow
    return image

def preprocess(x, y):
    def func(x, y):
        x = json.loads(x)
        x_img1 = read_image(x['path'], x['rel']) # 3D image
        x_img2 = read_image(x['path-fork'], x['filter']) #2D image with different shape
        # image resizing will lose data
        
        y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(set(df['label'].values))) # todo: yeah, i'll optimize it never
        
        return (x_img1, x_img2), y

    _x, _y = tf.numpy_function(func, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    # _x.set_shape([256, 256, 3]) <--- previously i used to do this
    _y.set_shape([10])
    
    return _x, _y


# here `x` is an array of string, and those strings are actually json/dictionary
def tf_dataset(x,y, batch=16):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(16)
    return dataset
```

[image: multi input model with tf.data.Dataset]

Now it's throwing an error saying:

```
InternalError: Graph execution error:

Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_30745]
```

Here is the notebook and data(same data being replicated): https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/25975541c888aa9bf865ad1827010907

Comment: So, you have 3 input in total, a 3D input (uniform shape), and 2D inputs but with different shape, is it correct? In your code, you comment that `x_img2` builds with different shapes but in writing you mention that `x_img2` is 32 x 64! Please elaborate.

Comment: @Innat 2D image's shape is different than the shape of 3D image... else I could have tried concatenating them...

Comment: I think it's doable but why you concern about set_shape attributes. Have you tired reshape method? Furthermore, if possible, avoid use py function, instead save your image in disk after reading via json object. Also, check this in case https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849164/9215780

Comment: Hey @Innat, the article you referred was really insightful... BUT from modeling perespective... my question focused more on DATASET... so it's was helpful, but still not helpful...

Comment: Can u share dummy data if possible?

Comment: hey @Innat... here is the notebook and data: https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/25975541c888aa9bf865ad1827010907.... had to make some modification, to share it publicly...