# Multitask learning to classify on dog images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm trying to train a multitask classification model (mobilenet). Basically, a single model that given an image of a dog, it classifies both the color and the breed. Each dataset simply has directories for each class, and images inside those classes. [Here](https://filebin.net/5or5r8h2mswzbmhe) is a sample subset of the dataset. Eventually, I need to cover 5 color classes and 10 breeds.

When I run it, I get an error `logits and labels must be broadcastable`. How to fix it?

**UPDATE**: initially, I had two different datasets for the two task. But apparently it mqkes it very difficult to solve. Let's assume I have a single dataset annotated for both tasks (color and breed).

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Set the directories for the color and breed datasets
color_data_dir = './color_dataset'
breed_data_dir = './breed_dataset'

# Define the input shape for the MobileNet model
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)

# Create an input layer for clarity and potential customization
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)

# Load the MobileNetV2 model (excluding the top fully connected layers)
base_model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer)

# Add task-specific fully connected layers for color classification
color_branch = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
color_branch = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name='color_output')(color_branch)

# Add task-specific fully connected layers for breed classification
breed_branch = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
breed_branch = Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='breed_output')(breed_branch)

# Create the multi-task model with both branches
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[color_branch, breed_branch])

# Compile the model with appropriate loss functions for each task
model.compile(loss={'color_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'breed_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Set up data generator for the combined color and breed datasets
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)

class MultiTaskDataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, color_data_dir, breed_data_dir, batch_size, target_size):
        self.color_data_dir = color_data_dir
        self.breed_data_dir = breed_data_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.target_size = target_size

        self.color_data = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
            directory=color_data_dir,
            target_size=target_size[:2],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical'
        )

        self.breed_data = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
            directory=breed_data_dir,
            target_size=target_size[:2],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical'
        )

    def __len__(self):
        return min(len(self.color_data), len(self.breed_data))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        color_batch, color_labels = self.color_data[index]
        breed_batch, breed_labels = self.breed_data[index]

        # Concatenate the batches along the batch dimension
        return tf.concat([color_batch, breed_batch], axis=0), [color_labels, breed_labels]

# Create an instance of the custom data generator
data_gen = MultiTaskDataGenerator(color_data_dir, breed_data_dir, batch_size=32, target_size=input_shape)

# Train the model on both tasks simultaneously using the custom data generator
model.fit(
    data_gen,
    epochs=1
)
```

And here is the full stack trace:

```
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Found 11 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 6 images belonging to 3 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\test\train.py", line 73, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "\test\train.py", line 73, in <module>
      model.fit(
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1783, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1377, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1360, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1349, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1127, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1185, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 143, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 270, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 2221, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5581, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[17,6] labels_size=[6,3]
         [[{{node categorical_crossentropy_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_21323]
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the dataset (few of them to test the possible solutions)?

Comment: @Innat Yes, just a sample subset: https://filebin.net/5or5r8h2mswzbmhe

Comment: I see. You have two different dataset and each contains 3 classes. This is not conventional way to do this task. The dataset should be one and target can be more than 1 (multiple, i.e. breed, color, etc). For general understanding, could you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849164/9215780) and let me know your thought.

Comment: Yeah the datasets are different and the number of classes for each task is different too (in my sample, 4 and 3). I saw your link. Too complex for me to understand. But using that, how would we need to change my training code above?

Comment: I think you need to re-organize your data first. Think of it, if you pass a sample, i.e. 'a.png` to the model, the target should be its 'breed' and 'color`.  That makes it multi-task. But currently according to your data set and the above dataloader, you concat two different dataset. So, at training time if a sample, i.e. 'a.png' from the combined dataset is passed to the model, what should be the output! This would makes the training complex.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also train a model on dataset A first, then save the weight. Next, freeze the encoder of this model and add a new layer for dataset B. So, at the end, you have one common encoder or backbone and two different target layer. This should work, I think.

Comment: Yeah I have to annotate them and form a single dataset. I need a single model

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you may need to reorganize the dataset. The ideal data format for this task would be like as follows:

```bash
df.head()
image_path  breed_category   color_category
a.png         bulldog            black
b.png         germanshepherd     white
...
```

And from this we can build the dataloader that yield a sample and two corresponding targets. But in your case, you have two datasets, each containing different classes. Also the sample ids are different. Something like:

```bash
df.head()
image_path  breed_category   color_category
a.png           NaN             black
b.png         germanshepherd     NaN
...
```

AFAIK, this is unusual setup for such modelling. But at the same time, it is not impossible to make it work but this brings unnecessary training complexities.

```py
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        color_batch, color_labels = self.color_data[index]
        breed_batch, breed_labels = self.breed_data[index]

        # Concatenate the batches along the batch dimension
        return tf.concat([color_batch, breed_batch], axis=0), 
               [color_labels, breed_labels]
```

Instead, you can build two model for training and later build a multi-output model from these two models. Here is how:

```py
color_data = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=color_data_dir,
    target_size=input_shape[:2],
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

breed_data = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=breed_data_dir,
    target_size=input_shape[:2],
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
Found 11 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 13 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

```py
def encoder(input_layer):
    x = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer)
    return x

def color_layer(backbone, num_classes=1):
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(backbone.output)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='color_output')(x)
    return x

def breed_layer(backbone, num_classes=1):
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(backbone.output)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='breed_output')(x)
    return x
```

**encoder**

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
backbone = encoder(input_layer)
```

Model for color feature.

```py
color_branch = color_layer(backbone, num_classes=4)
color_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=color_branch)
color_model.compile(
    loss={'color_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
    optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
color_model.fit(color_data, epochs=4) # OK
color_model.save('color_model')
```

Model for breed feature.

```py
# we can freeze the backbone here
# as these dataset contains same type of object.
# but this is optional.
backbone.trainable = False

breed_branch = breed_layer(backbone, num_classes=4)
breed_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=breed_branch)
breed_model.compile(
    loss={'breed_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
    optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
breed_model.fit(breed_data, epochs=4) # OK
breed_model.save('breed_model')
```

Now, for inference, we can do

```py
color_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('color_model')
breed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('breed_model')

def inference_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
    color_output = color_model(input_layer)
    breed_output = breed_model(input_layer)
    multi_task = Model(
        inputs=input_layer, outputs=[color_output, breed_output]
    )
    return multi_task
    
pred_model = inference_model()
```

```
x, _ = next(iter(breed_data))
x[0].shape # (224, 224, 3)
a, b = pred_model(x[0][None, ...])
a.numpy().argmax(-1) # array([0])
b.numpy().argmax(-1) # array([3])
```

Here the cost is, you need to train and inference the model twice. Though inference pipeline can be optimized further with single model. For example, we can save the encoder, top color and breed branch separately. And in inference time, we get the output feature from encoder and pass them to top layer of color and breed branch.

---

### Update

> Would you be able to add that piece as well with the complete code? So I won't have to circle back in few weeks once annotations is compelete.

Based on your above comment, here are some demonstration about how to build a dataframe and use it to build a `tf.data` dataloader API. As mentioned here, your current dataset looks like below.

```bash
df.head()
image_path  breed_category   color_category
a.png           NaN             black
b.png         germanshepherd     NaN
...
```

My upcoming explanation would consider above cases, where I will label the `nan` as `-1` and ignore it while computing the losses. So, if you can manage to complete annotation (as mentioned), please consider this.

> Also an important note, the following code is written in `keras 3 (not 2)`. That's because I have found a possible bug while using loss method to ignore `-1` class label in `keras 2` which seems resolves in `keras 3`. Reported [here](https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/issues/734). So, if you want to try the following code with your current data, you may need to update to `keras 3`. But if you use your updated data (proper labelling), then you don't need to worry about it. Because there should be no `-1` as label.

**create dataframe**

```py
data = []
breed_cat = {
    "Unknown": -1, # remove it for updated dataset
    "husky": 0,
    "goldenretriever": 1,
    "germanshepherd": 2,
    "bulldog": 3,
}
color_cat = {
    "Unknown": -1, # remove it for updated dataset
    "white": 0,
    "black": 1,
    "gray": 2,
    "yellow": 3,
}
```

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(color_data_dir):
    for file in tqdm(files):
        image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        color, breed = os.path.basename(root), "Unknown"
        data.append(
            {
                'image_path': image_path, 
                'breed_category': breed, 
                'color_category': color,
                'breed_category_numerals': breed_cat[breed],
                'color_category_numerals': color_cat[color]
            }
        )


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(breed_data_dir):
    for file in tqdm(files):
        image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        breed, color = os.path.basename(root), "Unknown"
        data.append(
            {
                'image_path': image_path, 
                'breed_category': breed, 
                'color_category': color,
                'breed_category_numerals': breed_cat[breed],
                'color_category_numerals': color_cat[color]
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.breed_category_numerals.value_counts()
df.color_category_numerals.value_counts()
```

**create dataloader**

Here we will see how to build a multi-output dataloader. There can be multiple way to do this, here is one of them. Notice, how we pack the desired label(s) and zip them with input.

```py
batch_size = 3
input_size = 224

def decode_image(item):
    file_bytes = tf.io.read_file(item)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_bytes, channels = 3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (input_size, input_size)) 
    return img / 255.

dataset_sample = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df['image_path'].values)
dataset_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        df['breed_category_numerals'].values, 
        df['color_category_numerals'].values
    )
)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_sample, dataset_labels))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (decode_image(x), y))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size * 8)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
x, y = next(iter(dataset))
```

If you are new to `tf.data` API, please check some online [resource](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data). Some syntax might looks similar to you, i.e. `tf.data.shuffle`.

**loss method**

As mentioned, I set `ignore_class=-1` to ignore those class label. When you have your updated dataset, remove this parameter.

```py
from keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
        y_true, y_pred, ignore_class=-1
    )
    return loss
```

**model**

```py
input_shape = (input_size, input_size, 3)
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
base_model = MobileNetV2(
    include_top=False, input_tensor=input_layer, input_shape=input_shape
)

gap = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
breed_branch = Dense(
    breed_num_class, activation='softmax', name="breed"
)(gap)
color_branch = Dense(
    color_num_class, activation='softmax', name="color"
)(gap)

model = Model(
    inputs=input_layer, 
    outputs=[breed_branch, color_branch]
)
```

**compile**

```py
model.compile(
    loss={
        "breed" : custom_loss,
        "color" : custom_loss,
    },
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
)
```

**fit**

```py
model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=30
)
Epoch 1/30
8/8 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4s 47ms/step - loss: 2.5717
Epoch 2/30
8/8 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 47ms/step - loss: 1.2192
Epoch 3/30
8/8 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 45ms/step - loss: 0.4062
Epoch 4/30
8/8 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 49ms/step - loss: 0.2657
Epoch 5/30
8/8 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0956
```

Comment: Oh I see. Just bc the datasets are different, I have to have 2 models. We need only one inference due to limits. So I have to annotate the datasets and merge them into a single one. How would the code look like for a single dataset?

Comment: If you can manage to build single dataset (a sample and its corresponding labels), I would suggest to first create a dataframe (csv), as showed in the answer at the beginning. And next, use `tf.data` API to build the dataloader.

Comment: I see. Would you be able to add that piece as well with the complete code? So I won't have to circle back in few weeks once annotations is compelete.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Thanks. But your update is still for cases where there are 2 separate datasets right? Let's assume I have one single dataset with both breed and color included as a CSV. 
Maybe organize your answer like this: a) a single dataset. b) 2 saparate datasets

Comment: Here you only need change the dataframe (csv) creation based on your updated dataset. And rest of the code (dataloader, model etc) remain same.

Comment: Is it the df variable above? How should I create it? Sorry I have limited experience with dataframe.

Comment: This might help. https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_dataframes.asp